# Using PIP to install Pillow in a Flatpak

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library, flatpak-builder

I've added a new function to a Python program which works when I run the program on my PC, but it isn't working in my Flatpak. I assumed that it was probably because the Pillow version on my PC (8.3.2) is rather more recent than that in the Flatpak manifest (5.4.1). The problem is that I can't get the Flatpak to build with the later version. I'm no expert on PIP or Flatpaks. Relevant part of manifest:

```
  - name: python3-pillow
    buildsystem: simple
    build-commands:
      - pip3 install --no-index --find-links="file://${PWD}" --prefix=${FLATPAK_DEST} Pillow
    sources:
      - type: file
        #    url: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/7e/443be24431324bd34d22dd9d11cc845d995bcd3b500676bcf23142756975/Pillow-5.4.1.tar.gz
        #    sha256: 5233664eadfa342c639b9b9977190d64ad7aca4edc51a966394d7e08e7f38a9f
        # try later version of pillow
        url: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/archive/refs/tags/8.3.2.tar.gz
        sha256: 8252b6b514aed2743abb5b7259b3253d6c4bf86902b9c5acd33fe79d24ec7b2f
```

Relevant part of Flatpak building output:

```
=======================================================================
Building module python3-pillow in /home/me/.flatpak-builder/build/python3-pillow-8
========================================================================
Running: pip3 install --no-index --find-links="file://${PWD}" --prefix=${FLATPAK_DEST} Pillow
Looking in links: file:///run/build/python3-pillow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pillow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Pillow
Error: module python3-pillow: Child process exited with code 1
END ================================================================================================
```

It looks as though it fails to download the tarball, but if I put the address into a browser, it downloads.

Comment: `--no-index` disables access to the download site; where from do you expect `pip` to download if downloading is disabled?

Comment: As I said in my OP "I'm no expert on PIP", so I had no idea what "--no-index" did. The manifest was written for me - and from what you write it must have been wrong from the start. Perhaps it worked because 5.4.1 was available to flatpak-builder from somewhere.

Comment: Removing "--no-index" results in: {several repeatedl errors}
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pillow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Pillow
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
Error: module python3-pillow: Child process exited with code 1
END ================================================================================================

Comment: Those {several repeated errors} are most probably network errors: for some reasons that you omitted `pip` cannot connect to pypi.org to download packages and check the latest version of the very `pip`.

Comment: Previously omitted due to lack of space: WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4b74181520>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pillow/

Comment: Local DNS/network errors. Not related to `pip` at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248182/discussion-between-phd-and-chrisofbristol).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that pip is searching for a file in `$PWD` (/run/build/python3-pillow/) and it can't find a file that matches your system and your python version. So eather you didn't download any thing due to an error in the manifest file or you are downlaoding the wrong file.

I can't find any errors in the manifest, at least on the part that you posted.

Have you tried to use a wheel file rather then a `tar.gz` archive?

A list of them for the latest `pillow` version are [here](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/#files).
I don't know what runtime you are using for flatpak but the (org.freedesktop.Sdk-21.08) runtime has `python v3.9.9` and i can assume that your app is for `x86_64` so i think that [Pillow-9.2.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/01/61/3ff85fb4bb596ce3d223c8fcf93c8df5c12bc8899dfb4fb3cb1c5b20dd5f/Pillow-9.2.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl) should work with you.